# Laravel marketplace app with single-shop maintenance mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

My project is a custom multi-tenancy application (I don't use any specific package for this purpose). At a global level I have the Laravel maintenance mode implemented and it works perfectly. Through a call to an endpoint of my API, this mode can be activated when I want the entire platform to be in maintenance mode. Also in this action I establish a preview bypass with the 'secret' option in my controller:

```
Artisan::call('down --secret="preview"');
```

I have a requirement that is to apply the same for each instance of the application, in isolation. So each store can apply its own maintenance mode when it considers it. To achieve this,  so far I use a middleware that returns a 503 if the shop.maintenancemode field is on in certain routes:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
    $shop = \App\Shop::find($request->idShop);
    if(!$shop->maintenancemode){
        return $next($request);
    }
    else{
        return response()->view('errors.503')->setStatusCode(503);
    }
}
```

I think this is not the best way to do it. Also I need to set the bypass with the access secret token in the same way as in global mode (like Laravel's built-in mode).
I know that for example I could create a new field shop.tokenmaintenance and check it in this middleware, but as I said, the option to use this middleware no longer seems correct to me beforehand.
My question is: could I use Laravel's built-in maintenance mode mechanism individually, for each store? How to get it? I appreciate any ideas.

Thanks in advance.